# Oracle SQL Error: ORA-00923: From Keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle8

When I use the following sql command for Oracle:

```
SELECT CATEGORY,ANTIGENNAME,LATINCOMPOSITION,HYCORCODE,FDACLEARANCE, LISTAGG(ORCHARDCODE, ';')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORCHARDCODE) as code
from tablename
group by HYCORCODE
```

I'm seem to be getting a ORA-00923 error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

What could be causing the error to show up?

Comment: we don't all know the Oracle error codes by memory, post the full error message, please ;)    Also, unrelated, I believe you're going to get another error because you haven't got enough columns in the group by clause ;)

Comment: Sorry about that, it is ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: What is your specific Oracle release of 11g? Listagg is only supported in Release2.

Comment: Let me ask the admin. I'm not sure what the version is.

Comment: You could try to get it with `select * from v$version;`

Comment: It is oracle 8g so I'm guessing the LISTAGG function will not work.

Comment: Right, then that is it. Notice that you tagged your question with 11g.  That was misleading. All would have pointed you to this problem within 2 secs had you tagged it correctly :-)  I have updated your tags just now.

Comment: That is fine, this can be closed. I wasn't sure it what version it was.

Comment: You can close it by accepting an answer.

Comment: I don't understand the choice of the accepted answer. The reason for the error message is clearly related to your Oracle version, no?

Comment: @Kevin, could you please come back to this? You have really marked the wrong answer as accepted...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`LISTAGG` is not available in your version of Oracle. Check your version with this statement:

```
select * from v$version;
```

`LISTAGG` is only available on versions >= 11.**`2`**.x

From ["Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2) New Features in Data Warehousing"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/whatsnew.htm#DWHSG8060):

> **Analytic Functions**
>
> New SQL analytic functions have been introduced that enable you to list (or concatenate) measure values within a group (`LISTAGG`).

Answer (score 0):

`code` is not a reserved word, so I don't think it needs to be quoted (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm)).

However, you have an aggregation function, so you need the correct columns in the `group by`:

```
SELECT CATEGORY, ANTIGENNAME, LATINCOMPOSITION, HYCORCODE, FDACLEARANCE, 
       LISTAGG(ORCHARDCODE, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORCHARDCODE) as code
from tablename
group by CATEGORY, ANTIGENNAME, LATINCOMPOSITION, HYCORCODE, FDACLEARANCE;
```

This definitely fixes a problem with your query.  I'm not sure if it will fix your particular error.  When I leave out columns from the `group by`, I get "ORA-00979 (not a GROUP BY expression)."

Comment: Upvote for the willingness to go beyond the immediate error reported by OP and to point out other things that must be fixed.