# LISTAGG does not work in Oracle Cloud

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-bi

I am trying to run the query below

```
select organization_id
  , listagg(secondary_inventory_name, ',') within group(order by secondary_inventory_name) as the_list
from inv_secondary_inventories
group by organization_id
```

, but it keeps giving this error:

```
oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL Error: ORA-00923: From Keyword not found where expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562364/oracle-sql-error-ora-00923-from-keyword-not-found-where-expected) - Specifically the answer suggesting that listagg is only available on version 11.2.x and newer (just a guess)

Comment: I see that you identified this as an Oracle BI issue. Your syntax looks fine and I suspect you are on 11.2 or greater (you would need to confirm).  Could this be this issue (similar error), " ODI Jobs Failing With ORA-00923 error (Doc ID 2155960.1)"?

Comment: @JNevill My version is `Oracle Business Intelligence 11.1.1.9.0`.  I guess this is the issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
select organization_id
  , listagg(secondary_inventory_name, ',') within group(order by secondary_inventory_name) as the_list
from inv_secondary_inventories
group by organization_id
```

The above is your query. Just keep the `listagg` statement in brackets and that would do magic..

```
select organization_id
  ,( listagg(secondary_inventory_name, ',') within group(order by secondary_inventory_name) )as the_list
from inv_secondary_inventories
group by organization_id
```

Comment: The brackets solve the problem perfectly